# token variable in shiny server r

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to understand what is token in shiny server. If i print session,

I get following:

```
Public:
   .....

Private:
   ....
   singletons: 12b282b6c4e1ec3cee386f4ca6165aafc4731a84
   token: 6a76ae3300237dea44123119624d5293
   ....
```

what is this token, I tried to search but didn't get any where, I was not able to find in session {shiny}  help